# How to use awk to filter a complex line?

Tags: shell, awk

I have a file with this syntax:

`key1 | key2 | key31:value31, key32:value32, ...| key4`

I want to filter all the lines with specific key and value in the third section.

For example, in the following test, I want filter all lines with age=13, more I want to user key in $3 to filter such as with key age and age >= 15.

`GET|20150715|age:13,height:11,width:12|Mike
POST|20150715|age:13,width:11|Tom
GET|20150715|height:11,width:11|Lily`

Can I use awk to do this?

Comment: Provide sample data from your input file and show some attempt.

Comment: I'm new to awk, I can only use awk $3 to get the third section, which is `age:13,height:11,width:12` in the first line, but I don't know what to do next.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

quick and dirty way:

```
 awk -F'|' '$3~/age:13/' file
```

It is "dirty" because, if someone was old enough, say `age:135`, it will be listed too,  also if there was no `age:13` in your `$3` but `package:13` the line would be outputted as well. But this one-liner is quick shot, you can try if it works for your real data.

#### update for new requirement:

since OP said he has gnu awk available, this line should work:

```
awk -F'|' -v value="12" 
   '$3~/age:/{v=gensub(".*age:([0-9]*).*","\\1","G",$3);if(v>value)print}' file
```

- You can change the `-v value="12"` to the value condition you want to check, e.g. `15, 17....`
- this one-liner will output the lines that age:value (in the 3rd column) greater than the value you given
- If you want to check smaller, equals... you change the `if(v... value)` check.

Here is a test with one line age value `<13`:

```
kent$  cat f
GET|20150715|age:13,height:11,width:12|Mike
xxxGET|20150715|age:10,height:11,width:12|Mike
POST|20150715|age:13,width:11|Tom
GET|20150715|height:11,width:11|Lily

kent$  awk -F'|' -v value="12" '$3~/age:/{v=gensub(".*age:([0-9]*).*","\\1","G",$3);if(v>value)print}' f
GET|20150715|age:13,height:11,width:12|Mike
POST|20150715|age:13,width:11|Tom
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I may need some more advanced features, for exmaple with age >= 13. Could I use regular expression to implement it?

Comment: I know awk can use $i to filter the line. In my case, it's sort of like nested awk, first get $3 and then split it and test each section, at last print the whole line. I'm new to shell and awk, I don't know how to implement it.

Comment: @Jayce you should put all requirements in your question when you posted it. not add new requirements by editing, this will make all answers fail. Who knows after my update if there is another new requirement coming....

Comment: I'm sorry, after comments on your answer, I have updated my question. Excuse me.

Comment: @Jayce do you have gnu awk?

Comment: Yes, I use awk in Linux.

Comment: Sorry to disturb, one more little question, I put the command in a shell, value can be passed through script parameter, how can I pass age as a parameter to shell script?